# Getting an equal 15px border with a grid layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid layout that's responsive with a 15px coloured border, it works ok but it when there's multiple grids, it doubles up the border i.e 30px where it joins.

https://jsfiddle.net/exm8xsgx/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 25%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 15px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="one">two</div>
    <div class="one">three</div>
    <div class="one">four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is another method I've tried. When browser width is restricted, the grids start to stack up and the border doubles up again, it should always be 15px whether they are next to each other or stacked.

https://jsfiddle.net/7bxtt82r/24/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.one:first-child {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 20%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-left-width: 15px;
  border-top-width: 15px;
  border-bottom-width: 15px;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.one:not(:first-child) {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 20%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-left-width: 15px;
  border-top-width: 15px;
  border-bottom-width: 15px;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="one">two</div>
    <div class="one">three</div>
    <div class="one">four</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also don't know how many grids there will be so they will just continue to stack up.

Comment: why don't you use media queries?

Comment: try `box-sizing:border-box;`

Comment: @Vivick how would box-sizing:border-box; stop it doubling up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS table, and set `border-spacing` to `15px`, example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.one {
  display: table-cell;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="one">two</div>
  <div class="one">three</div>
  <div class="one">four</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you need the items to wrap for different viewport width, you can use flexbox + box-shadow + media queries.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 15px;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px red;
  background: white;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .one {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .one {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="one">two</div>
  <div class="one">three</div>
  <div class="one">four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your external borders can stay on 15px but the border which touches another one has to be devided by 2 if you want a clean look with a same border around.

I used a default border of 10px and 20px for those not touching each other. (You can do the opposite: default 20px and 10px for those touching)

I dealt with this while building my simon game [here](https://codepen.io/Genia/pen/pPjYOw)

```
 .squareCircled {
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      border: 10px solid gray;
}   
 .green {
      background-color:#01B600; /*green*/
      border-top-left-radius: 100%;
      border-top:20px solid gray;
      border-left:20px solid gray;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```